# How to dynamically define URL without hardcoding it in JavaScript file in ASP.NET Core MVC application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using the Dropzone plugin in my ASP.NET Core MVC application to upload files from the browser and perform further actions with them. In my site.js file, I'm setting the URL for the file upload using the following code:

```js
var currentUrl = window.location.pathname;
var segments = currentUrl.split('/');
var controllerName = segments[1];

var dropzone = new Dropzone("#my-dropzone", { 
    url: '/' + controllerName + '/upload'
});
```

I have six controllers, each handling different operations with the files, as well as `.cshtml` index pages for every controller. I can't figure out if there's a better way to set the URLs. I've seen some suggestions on the internet that I can manipulate this line in the `Layout.cshtml` page, but there was no clear answer on how to do it:

```
@await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
```

I was thinking about including script sections for every controller, but it makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using

```
@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString()?
```

I cannot completely understand witch part needs to be changed; However this part could be better by this change